# How to reuse a huge query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, common-table-expression, temp-tables

I have very huge query which takes data from many tables and group them by all non-calculated columns. And I need to reuse this query many times but with other grouping and filtering. In MSSQL I use CTE or temporary tables for such purpose but MySQL doesn't support CTE and I can't refer temporary table more than one time in the same query (this is sad and illogical limitation of MySQL).

```
SELECT 
    t1.VideoId, 
    t1.RegionId, 
    t1.CountryId, 
    t1.PerCountryCount,
    t2.PerRegionCount
FROM (
    SELECT 
        VideoId, 
        RegionId, 
        CountryId, 
        SUM(PlayCount) PerCountryCount
    FROM TrackedData
    GROUP BY VideoId, RegionId, CountryId
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        VideoId, 
        RegionId, 
        SUM(PlayCount) PerRegionCount
    FROM TrackedData
    GROUP BY VideoId, RegionId
) t2
```

This example is simplified but shows the problem. The t1 query has more detailed data and I want to reuse it in t2 query since in real project it is too hard to take data in t1 query (million rows, many filters and groupings, etc.). the second reason why I want to reuse this query is query length. I don't want repeat just a bit changed query which has around 60 rows of code.

Comment: You can create an explicit temp table (`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE...`).

Comment: @Vatev yes you do, but you can't refer to it more than one time. I need to query data from one data result but in different view and join them together, it means I need to refer temporary table in the same query at least 2 times which is not allowed by mysql.

Comment: @Vatev just run this test query in your workbench and you will get error "can't reopen table: t".  

`create temporary table t1 (id int);

insert into t1 values (1);

update t1 t
join (select max(id) id from t1) t2 on t.id = t2.id
set t.id = null;

drop temporary table t1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround in MySQL is to create multiple temporary tables. You can use a temporary table as a source to populate another one. This is the approach we use. (Yes, it would be more efficient to use a single temporary table, but MySQL doesn't allow the same temporary table to be referenced more than once.)

---

Another alternative is to create a regular table instead of a temporary table. There's lots of downsides to that. One big issue is tables that get abandoned aren't automatically dropped. If you go this route, you'll undoubtedly want:

- to use a separate database for these "temporary" work tables
- a regularly scheduled, periodic cleanup routine to drop old and abandoned tables
- a strict naming convention for the tables, tablename using a special prefix, followed by a datetime string, and the id of the session, and then the "name" of the table.

The cleanup routine can identify tables to be dropped by their age (based on the datetime string, but be aware of the implications of clients that change their timezone setting), and by the id of the session no longer existing in SHOW PROCESSLIST. (I used the word "and" there... we'd want to drop tables that met either of those criteria.)

The code that creates these work tables should drop these tables, but even with that, there's going to be abnormal terminations that leave tables behind.

---

(Personally, I'd avoid this second approach, and just go with using multiple temporary tables.)

As a demonstration of using multiple temporary tables:

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _t1_ AS
  SELECT VideoId
       , RegionId
       , CountryId
       , SUM(PlayCount) AS PerCountryCount
    FROM TrackedData
   GROUP BY VideoId, RegionId, CountryId
  ;
  CREATE INDEX _t1_IX1
    ON _t1_ (VideoId, RegionId, PerCountryCount);

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _t2_ AS
  SELECT VideoId
       , RegionId
       , SUM(PerCountryCount) AS PerRegionCount 
    FROM _t1_
   GROUP BY VideoId, RegionId
  ;
  CREATE INDEX _t2_IX1
    ON _t2_ (VideoId, RegionId, PerRegionCount)
  ;
```

Note that having suitable indexes defined on *t1* will improve performance of populating *t2*.

Comment: I thought to use first way but I hoped I'll find some more laconic approach.  However this is 100% way to achieve my result. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to limitations in MySQL, this is what we have to do. That's just the price we pay for using MySQL. If there's a more laconic workaround, I don't know of it. At least MySQL lets us create indexes on temporary tables. There's no way to specify that an inline view should be indexed. (Not in 5.5 or earlier; in a later version of MySQL, there's some (limited) automatic indexing on derived tables.) I typically use temporary tables for performance, as workaround to a lack of indexes on derived tables.)

Answer (score 9):

You can reuse queries using the concept of views:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html

Simple example, in practice **big_ass_select_query** probably has a bunch of joins

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS big_ass_select_query;

CREATE VIEW big_ass_select_query AS
SELECT col1 from table1;
```

Use it as a normal query

```
SELECT * FROM big_ass_select_query WHERE col1 > 1;
```